# Why can I get number of carries in such a strange method?

Tags: prime-numbers

Here is the thing. I solved kata on Codewars with task: [Find number of carries.](https://www.codewars.com/kata/529fdef7488f509b81000061)

I solved this task trivially. I reversed both numbers and sum each digit one by one. I accumulate `sum / 10` (integer division). I increase counter each time when accumulator isn't equal `0`. My solution is 41 lines-long. I submitted my solution and I founded another solution and I don't understand how to works! I tried it on paper all works!
Please explain it to me.

The smart solution

1. sum_a = sum of digits for first number
2. sum_b = sum of digits for second number
3. sum_sum = sum of digits for sum of numbers
4. (sum_a + sum_b - sum_sum) / 9(integer division)

examples:

```
### first
sum(543) = 12
sum(3456) = 18

543 + 3456 = 3999
sum(3999) = 30

(12 + 18 - 30) => 0/9 = 0 right!

### second
sum(1927) = 19
sum(6426) = 18

1927 + 6426 = 8153
sum(8153) = 17

(19 + 18 - 17) => 20/9 = 2 right!
```

Comment: You should start with the formal definition of the question, or at the very least, a link to the external problem. It only became clear what you are asking in the examples.

Comment: How can the definition be better in your opinion? @ThomasAndrews
Sorry, I fixed it!

Comment: “Find number of carries” is vague, at best. Be specific. “When doing addition of two numbers  base $10$ 
 using the standard technique…” There is nothing implicit in addition about carries. Rather, it is peculiar to the algorithm we apply to the process of addition given a certain notation for numbers.

Comment: Okay, thank you @ThomasAndrews for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you didn’t do any carries, then you’d get $$1927+6426=7(13)4(13)$$

and $$7+13+4+13=(1+9+2+7)+(6+4+2+6)$$

But each time we do a carry, in the left we reduce one term on the left by $10$ and one term is increased by $1.$ So we get $9$ reduction in terms with each carry.

The tricky part is you need to consider the cases when a carry in turn causes a carry.

For example: $56+47=103.$

We start with  $9(13)=56+47,$ and $9+13=(5+6)+(4+7),$ with one carry to get to $(10)+3.$ This reduces the sum by $9,$ but we need to do one more carry to get $103.$ That reduces the digit sum again by $9.$

It takes an inductive argument to prove this result, and technically it requires a full definition of the algorithm of addition.

For the sum of three numbers. In the sum of the two integers, we can only carry $1$ per carry. But when summing $19+29+59=107,$ there are two carries, one of $1,$ the other of $2.$

This works more general, for sums $k$. When $k\geq 11,$ it depends on how you count a “carry” when you get a digit sum plus carry $\geq 100.$